# python: how to write daemon in Linux

Tags: python, linux

I have a .py file that is ran by:

python a.py &

I am using a ssh to run the command, after it I have to log off. I find after some time the process is exited. I suspect it's Linux send some signal to it? I think if I can make the daemon then I can avoid this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although nohup will work, it's a quick and dirty solution.  To make a proper daemon process you need to use SysV init or (If you are running Ubuntu 6.10+ or Fedora 9+) upstart.

Here's a simple script that starts a.py and restarts it whenever it gets killed (up to 5 times inside a 5 minute span):

```
respawn

respawn limit 5 300

exec python /path/to/a.py
```

Then just put that script in `/etc/init/`.

Upstart has a lot more options too.  Checkout the [Quick Start](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 5):

This implementation looks reasonable: http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/

Answer (score 4):

I've been very happy with `daemonize.py` from Brian Clapper, based on FreeBSD's `daemon(1)`:

http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/

http://github.com/bmc/daemonize

Since January 2009 there is [PEP 3143](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/) which contains links to a proposed reference implementation, design goals, citations (Stevens) and other sources.

Answer (score 3):

Run it with 'nohup' to ignore signals when your shell exits:

```
nohup python a.py &
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the *screen* utility, allowing you to access multiple separate terminal sessions inside a single terminal window or remote terminal session.

This means that you can setup a screen session (with a name of your choice), start a program within it (for example using &), detach from the session, and reconnect at a later time.

To start an unnamed screen.

```
$ screen
```

To create a new session with a specific name use:

```
$ screen -S backup
```

-these both commands create a new persistent session, and you can use it as a regular terminal window, i.e., issue commands and run scripts.

If you want to leave the session without terminating it, use:

```
Ctrl+a d command (press and hold Ctrl, press and hold a, then press d) to detach from the session.
```

To see the list of runnging screens:

```
$ screen -ls
```

To attach a running screen to the console:

```
$ screen -R
```

The following key-combinations can be used, when a screen is running, and is attached to the console. All key kombinations begin with pressing control and a simultaneously.

```
ctrl+a d - detach the screen, and let it run without user interface (as described above)
ctrl+a c - create a new terminal
ctrl+a A - set the name of the current terminal
ctrl+a n - switch to next terminal
ctrl+a p - switch to prev terminal
ctrl+a " - list the of terminals
```